# How to use last modified date to cache single page for 1 hour?

Tags: caching, symfony

What I want to do is to cache a page for 1 hour. The thing is that I want to be able to set the case stale during this 1 hour period if my object is modified.

Here is my code so far:

```
$response = new Response();
$response->setLastModified(new \DateTime($lastModified));        
if ($response->isNotModified($this->getRequest()))
    return $response;
else
    $response->setCache(array(
        'public' => true,
        'max_age' => 3600, 
        's_maxage' => 3600,
    ));
```

The problem is the above code doesn't check lastModified. Once the 1 hour cache is created I have to wait full 60 minutes to see the changes I have made to my object ($lastModified).

Answer (score 0):

Here is [an example](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/http_cache.html#validation-with-the-last-modified-header) of caching page using Last-Modified header at the symfony2 documentation.

I think your mistake is that you tries to use Last-Modified and then rewrite it with Cache-Control header (max_age, s_maxage).

Comment: The thing is I want to use 2 methods in 1 example. Cache the page for 3 hours and mark cache as stale (during those 3 hours) if $object->getLastModified() has changed.